# What is the grammar of "to count" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

In the below sentence, what is the grammar of "is to count" and what is the meaning of the whole sentence?

> Kuhn's own account of science entails that what is to count as a problem is paradigm or community dependent.

Answer (score 4):

> *[Kuhn's own account of science]
>
> entails that
>
> [[what is **to count as** a problem]
>
> [is paradigm- or community-dependent]].*

*(Is) to count* is not a constituent by itself. There is a specific predicate, and a specific construction that the predicate is used in to give this impression.

The predicate is *count (as s.t.)*, in the sense of

- *He wasn't counted as a student because he wasn't here/he's not female/he's not enrolled yet.*

The construction the predicate is used in is one of the ways English distinguishes a future reference. The ***be to*** + `VP` construction refers to some scheduled or expected event in the future, usually involving change of location or status:

- *He **is to be inducted** tomorrow. She **is to accompany** him. They **are to take** the 8:15 to London.*

So the example sentence means that what Kuhn claimed (his "account of science") requires, in order to be true ("entails"), that whatever is supposed to count ("be important enough to qualify") as a "problem" (a **scientific** problem, in Kuhn's case) had to be either paradigm-dependent or community-dependent (or of course both).

Answer (score 2):

> *Kuhn's own account of science entails that* [*what is to count as a*
> *problem*] *is paradigm or community dependent*.

"Is to count" is not a grammatical unit, not a constituent, so it cannot as a whole be assigned to a category or function.

The bracketed element is a noun phrase in a 'fused relative construction' where the fusion involves "what", which is understood as "that which". The meaning of the sentence is:

> "*Kuhn's own account of science entails that that which is to count as a*
> *problem is paradigm or community dependent*".